# Filter rows in R by range of character numbers

Tags: r, string, filter, dplyr

I have a problem I have been fumbling with for a minute. I have a dataframe with a column of characters in the format 1146-01, 1148-02, 1132-11, etc. The first four digits are the julian number, the second two represent a sample number. I would like to filter based on month (ie the month of February would be 1132-**:1159:**) I have tried this:

```
dates <- c(1132:1159)
dates <- as.character(dates)

new <- data %>%
  filter(str_detect(Sample.Number, dates)) %>%
```

as well as using the %in% operator, but no such luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 2):

We could use `paste/str_c` with `collapse = "|"` to search for either one of them in `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
data %>%
     filter(str_detect(Sample.Number, str_c(dates, collapse="|")))
```

---

Or another option is to extract the number before the `-` with `parse_number` and use `%in%`

```
data %>%
     filter(readr::parse_number(Sample.Number) %in% dates)
```

Or with `substr` and `between`

```
data %>%
     filter(between(as.numeric(substr(Sample.Number)),
            as.numeric(first(dates), as.numeric(last(dates))))
```